# Python Discord Bot allow links

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

i'm trying to make a bot that allows only links and image with or without text.
This code i wrote delete every links i post because bot see the link like a normal text.
This is the code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if str(message.channel) == "multimedia" and message.content != "" and not message.attachments:
        await message.channel.purge(limit=5)

client.run('token')
```

I suppose to use a regex but i don't know ho to write it in the right way to tell allow every link that start with http or https

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the message begins with `https://` , and check if the message has any attachments

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
      if message.author.bot:
         return #allow bots to send messages on the channel even if they don't include an image/URL
      if message.content.startswith("https://") or message.attachments != []:
         await message.channel.send("This is a link or an image!")
      else:
          await message.delete()
```